# Where do I find a private key in litewallet.io?

Tags: wallet, private-key, litecoin

I have created this public key LUv2h4kHH21bJSmab2UAvBarLmSckWFASS in a mobile app called litewallet.io which can be found here https://litewallet.io/ but I do not see an option in litewallet to display private key.
Instead the litewallet secured my account with 12 words phrase.
I need private key because I want to import that to my Litecoin Core wallet.
How do I find the private key of that public key in LiteWallet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ (offline), import your 12 seed then select litecoin on coin tab.

Comment: lol, im not giving anybody my 12 seeds as they can steal